# How do i compare a value to a multiple list items in a dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, listitem

I'm trying to do a logic here where by if an item from db exists in part of the dropdownlist ListItem it will have that item selected, else it will display the new item in a textbox and have the "Others" selected in the dropdownlist.

This is what I have so far

```
string gameData = readGame["gTitle"].ToString();
string gameTitle = ddlgameTile.Items.ToString();

if (printHouseData == gameTitle)
{
   ddlgameTile.SelectedIndex = ddlgameTile.Items.IndexOf(ddlgameTile.Items.FindByValue(gameData));
}
else
{
   txtNewGame.Text = readGame["gTitle"].ToString();
   ddlgameTile.SelectedIndex = ddlgameTile.Items.IndexOf(ddlgameTile.Items.FindByValue("Others"));
}
```

I tried using Foreach loop and for loop, it still would not work (properly).  It only gets the if-else logic by the last ListItem which is the "Others".

Comment: `ddlgameTile.Items.ToString()` is pointless, it just returns the type-name of `ListItemCollection`. I assume that this is the reason for your issue since you are using it in the `if`-statement. However, i'm not sure what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I know, I just had to put something there temporary.  If I would to hard-code the `gameTitle`, it works like i expect it to do.  I'm just trying to compare to the rest of the List Items

Comment: Why do you have to put some garbage there temporarily?

Comment: I'm still thinking the correct method to assign the `gameTitle` variable.

Comment: What do you want the gameTitle to be? I am not sure what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: I want it to be a collection of ListItems in the DropDownList

Comment: ddlgameTile.Items is already a collection of items. You can iterate through this.

Comment: What is the source of the dropdownlist? Have you hardcoded the values in which case you will get a ListItemsCollection which you can iterate. If have you bound a datatable to it you can get it by using DataSource property of the dropdown and then iterate through the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `gameData` is the *db* item you want to select if it does exist, you can use [`ListItemCollection.FindByValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbyvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the item or `null` if it does not exist. Then you can set [`DropDownList.SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to select it:

```
string selectedValue = "Others";
if(ddlgameTile.Items.FindByValue(gameData) != null)
    selectedValue = gameData;
ddlgameTile.SelectedValue = selectedValue;
```

However, if you have set the `DataValueField` and `DataTextField` you have to use `FindByText`.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
        var compareTo = new ListItem("Title","Value");
        if (ddl.Items.Contains(compareTo))
        {
            var selectedIndex = ddl.Items.IndexOf(compareTo);
        }
        else
        {
            var selectedIndex = 
                 ddl.Items.IndexOf(new ListItem { Value = "Others", Text = "Others" });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I have the context of what you're trying to achieve right, try this:

```
foreach (string gameTitle in ddlgameTile.Items)
{
    if (printHouseData == gameTitle)
    {
        ddlgameTile.SelectedIndex = ddlgameTile.Items.IndexOf(ddlgameTile.Items.FindByValue(gameData));
    }
    else
    {
        txtNewGame.Text = readGame["gTitle"].ToString();
        ddlgameTile.SelectedIndex = ddlgameTile.Items.IndexOf(ddlgameTile.Items.FindByValue("Others"));
    }
}
```